# Problems with plotting extremely wide confidence interval for odds ratio

Tags: r, confidence-interval, odds-ratio, forest-plot

I am having problems with preparing the forest plot for the logistic regression. I am comparing the effect of 3 treatments of complications. Here is the code that reproduces this:

```
library(finalfit)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mydata<- data.frame(list(Complications=c(rep(0,285),rep(1,70)),
                         Method=c(rep("Method1",66), rep("Method2",64),
                                  rep("Method3",155), rep("Method1",29),
                                  rep("Method3",41))))
mydata$Method<- factor(mydata$Method)

explanatory = c("Method")
dependent = c("Complications")
mydata %>%
  or_plot(dependent, explanatory)
```

Because Method2 does not lead to any complications, the OR confidence interval is extremely wide. I just want to shrink it for the plot to look reasonable.

I have tried to use breaks like

```
mydata %>%
  or_plot(dependent, explanatory, breaks=c(8e-135,0.1,1,100,5e+5))
```

but for some reason this does not work as well.

If anybody knows how to make this plot look nice, please kindly let me know.

Comment: This seems to be just about how to fudge a plot in R, so off-topic.

Comment: It might be better to omit one group as not relevant with an explanation rather than mess with the plot.

Comment: Dear @NickCox, thanks for your answer. I see your point but my question is more about just a setting when some confidence interval is much wider than other and I am wondering how to get this fixed in R, particularly within the "finalfit" package if somebody is aware of course. I have seen arrows used for such purposes within the meta-analysis setting, but never seen something like this when plotting the Odds Ratios

Comment: Please see my first comment about coding requests.

Comment: Effect ratios should be plotted on the log scale (unequally spaced tick marks labeled on the original scale).